# Why do we write force = mass × acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, velocity

Force is directly proportional to mass and rate of change in velocity i.e., acceleration.  So why do we write force as mass times acceleration?  I mean why do we multiply mass by acceleration?

Comment: The answer to this question is very similar to the answer you accepted on your [previous question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743353/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why $F = m(v_f - v_0)/2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743353/)

Comment: *Why do we write force as mass times acceleration?* Because that agrees with what we experimentally observe happening in Nature. The point of physics is to quantitatively understand the real world.

Comment: Force is spatial rate of energy transference. When it is applied on an object, the object gains momentum or loss depending upon state of motion of an object and direction of applied force. It is never become constant instantaneously. When it becomes constant that means an object reach at equilibirium and rate of gain in momentum equals rate of loss in momentum.

Answer (score 4):

Isaac Newton observed that a body has a resistance (inertia) to a change in its velocity (acceleration).  This inertia is called mass.  Force is an effect on a body that changes its velocity; with no force the acceleration is zero.

Based on experimental evidence, Newton quantified Force as inertia (mass) times the change in velocity (acceleration).

Comment: what i always wonder is why is newtons law so accurate? I mean it almost feels like a 'mathematical concept' (like velocity and acceleration, which are just logically deduced equations which are 100.00% accurate). It feels less like a 'Physics Formula' where we make a logical theory in atempt to quantify physical quantities(which are not as accurate as the mathematical concepts ofcourse). Such a simple equation F=ma, such big implications. Amazing.

Comment: In my opinion, textbooks do not emphasize enough that physics concepts are based on observations and experiments, and only those concepts that continue to be shown valid by experiments survive.  Geniuses such as Newton, Euler and Einstein have the intelligence to develop the valid concepts in terms of general mathematical relationships.

Answer (score 2):

(a) $\mathbf F =m\mathbf a$ satisfies the (experimentally confirmed) proportionalities that you mention: for a given $\mathbf a$, doubling $m$ doubles the $\mathbf F$ that we need, and, for a given $m$, doubling $\mathbf a$ also doubles the $\mathbf F$ that we need. [And we can replace 'doubling' by multiplying by any factor, greater or less than 1.]

(b) But the above would still be the case for $\mathbf F =k\ m\mathbf a$ in which $k$ is any real number. Why, then, do we put $k=1$? We are only allowed to do this if we use special units for $\mathbf F$. For example, in the SI we measure force in N (newton). 1 newton is defined as the resultant force needed to give a mass of 1 kg an acceleration of 1 m s$^{-2}$. If we agree to measure $m$ in kg, $\mathbf a$ in m s$^{-2}$ and $\mathbf F$ in N, we can then write $\mathbf F =m\mathbf a$.